# Variance with multiple generic parameters/constraints

Tags: .net, generics, interface, variance

First off, I don't even know if the question is correct because I am not certain what, exactly, the issue is. Take these interfaces for starters:

```
public interface IItemContainer<TValue, TItem> where TItem : IItem<TValue>
{
    List<TItem> Items { get; set; }
}

public interface IItem<T>
{
    T Value { get; set; }
}
```

I implement it like so:

```
public class ItemContainer1<TValue> : IItemContainer<TValue, Item1<TValue>>
{
    public List<Item1<TValue>> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Item1<T> : IItem<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

Everything is working so far, but I am getting a "Cannot implicitly convert" cast error on below assignment:

```
IItemContainer<string, IItem<string>> container = new ItemContainer1<string>();
```

And I get `InvalidCastException` if I try casting like so:

```
IItemContainer<string, IItem<string>> container =
    (IItemContainer<string, IItem<string>>)new ItemContainer1<string>();
```

Something tells me I have either the generic parameter or the constraint wrong (or both). It's probably a variance issue which I have yet to fully wrap my head around. What do I need to do to make this work?

Edit: I am not a huge fan of the `TItem` parameter, but it's the only way I know to get the `List<TItem>` property to be of type `List<Item1<TValue>>` and not `List<IItem<TValue>>`.

Comment: Are you sure your collection interface should expose a settable `List<TITem>` property? Usually something vaguer *and* non-settable would be preferred. E.g. `ILIst<TItem> {get;}`. There's not much benefit in interfaces/generics if you're then forcing concrete types on implementations.

Comment: While I agree in general, I find that it is very unlikely I would reimplement the `List<>` or `Dictionary<,>` classes, so I tend to use the concrete classes for those 2 types but I do recommend looking into less specific types like `IEnumerable<>` or `ICollection<>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you want the list to be of type `Item1<TValue>` you can't cast it to the less specific `IItem<TValue>`.  A setter on a property of type `IItem<TValue>` should succeed for any valid implementer of the interface.  You either need to allow that list of be of type `IItem<TValue>`, which you have stated you don't want, or re-architect another way.

If you only need to read the list values as `IItem<TValue>`, as opposed to using the interface to create a new list, you can change your interface to read and cast the values.